# Altium: Find schematics which use a footprint from the library

Tags: schematics, altium, footprint

If I search for an item, and I find it's footprint, can I find which schematic/part it was referenced to. E.g. finding corresponding wiring/schematic symbol?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Schematic view (option only available in Schematic view).

Tools --> Footprint Manager.

On the left, sort by column "Current Footprint."  It will show to the left of that all part designators using that footprint.

[image]